# Looking to make Week-Long Calendar in C#

Tags: c#, calendar

I'm looking to mimic the UI in Microsoft Outlook how a user can view their schedule a week at a time.

I'm trying to avoid using ASP .NET and making it a webpage, but rather making it a local .exe (again similar to Outlook).

For those who aren't familiar with Outlook, here's what I'm after:

http://josh.st/blog/wp-content/2007/03/outlook-2007-week-calendar.jpg

I'm really after the UI and not so much a fully-functional calendar. It'd be a plus if I could limit the number of days shown during the week, too.

So I guess what I'm asking is if anyone is aware of any decent tools to accomplish this UI.

Comment: DevExpress has excellent control suites for both winforms and WPF, but if you ask me I'd never choose winforms for new projects. I consider it legacy.

Comment: You can try just building it yourself in WPF.  Just create a new WPF project in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Well... if you're looking for a decent one out of the box that you can modify, try telerik's calendar: http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/marketplace/publishers/coding-staff/codingstaff-calendar-for-sitefinity-

I've had good luck with feedback on this one, if you want one that looks exactly like outlook, you can you know... always code it yourself.  I doubt that there's anything that would be publicly available given the current state of copyright.